# Unknown code analysis error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am having an issue with code analysis. I am running vs 2012 on a win 8 machine. The error I am getting is:
CA0001  Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : An unknown error occurred while running Code Analysis. [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

That is all the info I get. I have tried looking at the CodeAnalysisLog.xml for each of the projects but they are all empty.

I have downloaded a new fresh copy of the trunk that everyone else is working from, and I am still getting this issue. No one else on my team is getting these, just me. I am guessing it has something to do with my machine and not the project since the code base works for everyone else.

I am at a loss, I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: do you have any custom rules applied?

Comment: No custom rules applied.

Comment: try closing visual studio, make a backup, deleting every ".sou" and ".csproj.user" then relaunch and test

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have deleted all csproj.user files and I had no .sou files. Still having the same issue. I believe this was the same state after checking out the solution fresh though.

Comment: .suo files are hidden. I think explorer is set to hide these files. Change the folder options to show hidden files.

Comment: Deleted .suo files and no change.

Comment: Comparing to others, are you running the same OS, and 32/64 bits? There may be a problem loading and building assemblies. You can try building 32 bits, try building all assemblies one at a time. Copy a complete folder from another team member, perhaps assemblies are not in the trunk, which should have been. Or references to locations outside the trunk.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all the unused temp files from C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Temp.(%temp%)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved my issue. This worked for me but I am not sure if it will work for anyone else having issues.

I ended up turning code analysis off for all 18 of my projects that were throwing this error. I built and ran the project successfully, and afterwards I turned on code analysis for all the projects I had turned it off for. It now works no problem.